# How to create/ set c # Windows form user control properties to obtain simple message pop-up windows

Tags: c#, winforms

It can be any message window like font windows shown within the image. The pop-up when we click the button edit at properties pane.
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `MessageBox.Show()`? I'm finding it impossible to figure out what you're asking. There are a bunch of words in your question, but they don't seem to work successfully together to express a meaningful question.

Comment: please look at the image! @ the propertygrid pane there is a font windows that will pop- up when the user click on buttonedit.  what i want is that insteade fo font windows to have just "hello world " message.

Comment: What do you want to do that can't be done with [`MessageBox.Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: nope! can you show me   how to implement the above font windows on my user control property.

Comment: "Nope" is not an answer to my question. And you now have prompted a second question: why did you previous say you want _instead_ of a font "window" (i.e. dialog) to _"have just 'hello world' message"_, but now you say you _do_ want _"the above font windows"_. It is not possible to answer a question that a) is not expressed clearly, and b) is different each day.

Comment: i know that word is not good. am very sorry about that.i didnt ask two question, what i want to say is that if you show me haw to come up with that font windows, i will customize it for my desire(i.e "hello world "  message that is handled @ my user control propertygrid pane and  when user click buttonedit it will pop-ups the message instead of font windows).

Comment: thé solution for my question!!! 

i got thé solution fro
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: If that other question and answer solve your problem, please close this question as a duplicate of that one. Click the "close" link under your question, select "duplicate", and paste the link to that question into the dialog box. Thanks!

Comment: This question should be closed as reader cannot get what was the author asking in the original version. It doesn't benefit readers on the site other than the author.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom PropertyGrid editor item which opens a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

The way to show a simple popup message containing a string is as follow:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello, world.");
```

Comment: thanks for your support!!!! i were messed up when asking  the question like the way i presented. any ways i got the answer from other source. i used UItypeEditor for that purpose.

Comment: Then you should answer your own question with the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a simple Message Box with this:

`MessageBox.Show("Message");`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has been already resolved almost 7 years ago. Please read the other answer's comment section!