# Design-time editing of a Dictionary object (WinForms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dictionary, editor, design-time

I've been able to create a WinForm as a custom editor for a custom object, but how do you get Visual Studio to use a WinForm as a custom editor for a dictionary of custom objects?

Even help understanding how to use a WinForm as a custom editor for a dictionary of integers, strings, or any other "normal" type would be helpful...

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form) answer?

Comment: Btw...do you have a sketch of what you want to achieve? It´s still unclear to me what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I read that - and got it to work.  The problem is that I'm not working with just one single object, but a Dictionary(Of string, CustomObject).  I can't get the editor to use a custom form for a Dictionary.  For that matter, I can't get the editor to use a custom form for ANY Dictionary, not even a Dictionary(Of Integer) for example.  It always shows me an empty Collection Dialog with the Add and Remove buttons disabled.

Comment: Have you trried creating your own dictionary class, implementing IDictionary or inheriting from Dictionary, holding a private Dictionary member variable? And use this class as your custom editor?

Comment: I have created an object inheriting from Dictionary, but I can't get it to use my custom editor.  That's the root of the question.

Comment: That´s beyond my knowledge. Maybe you can add the C# tag to widen the scope of your Q and get more attention. Or you ask in the MSDN forums.

Comment: I appreciate your help, @AlexB.  I'm trying an entirely different approach (again).